# Why was this answer deleted as rude/abusive?

Tags: discussion, spam

I'm quite surprised to see [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/314860/72179) go, especially with a "spam or rude/abusive" epitaph on its grave. From what I can see, the last revision of the answer had 24 upvotes, 2 downvotes and looked like this:

> It can be done, with a few precautions.
>
> Don't put them in the same bed with, especially when the batteries are charged.
>
> Don't put them in the upper bed, especially if the bed isn't sturdy.
>
> Don't heat them up when you sleep with them.
>
> Be careful about leaky or old batteries. Acid spill can be bad.
>
> I would also recommend against sleeping with them when they are being charged with or discharged at high current levels.
>
> It is generally safer to store them away from your bed, preferably in a acid resistive isothermal chamber.

Regardless of the usefulness of the answer, I believe that having a history of content deleted as abusive is a pretty strong black mark against the account (involving rate limits for questions, answers and comments and more CAPCHA) which the user doesn't seem to deserve.

Or did I miss something that happened behind the scenes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're missing some information. This particular user has only been with us for 5 months, but has had an unusually high number of issues raised against him. He's having a hard time fitting in here, and this is just one more problem among many. The moderators are trying to manage the situation as best we can.

Comment: But that doesn't address how that specific answer is either spam or abusive. It may be tongue in cheek but it's fairly factually accurate. A funny answer may merit a regular deletion, but not being marked as spam/abuse when there is nothing of the sort in it.

Comment: @Passerby: You'd have to speak to the person who raised the flag in the first place. Once it's raised, I would have to dismiss the flag first and then go back and delete the answer anyway. It's simpler to just delete it right away, while handling the flag. We moderators do try hard to be objective, but we are only human, after all -- and this particular user has created an unusually high workload for us.

Comment: What fitting in are you talking about? Who gave you the right to judge who fitts and who is unfit? Go to your high-school club of something and expel people from there.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum: The active participants in the community at large decide whether someone is not fitting in by raising flags on their posts and comments. It is then up to the elected moderators like myself to evaluate and address the issues that led to the flags.

Comment: Like a sheriff. Only sheriff is supposed to have law, while you (not personally, average you) just guess. Like seeing a word "cost" immediately provokes reflex of "shopping question".

Comment: @GregoryKornblum: It isn't "law", but moderators do work within a specific set of guidelines established by Stack Exchange. You're obviously upset about something, and I've seen [your other rant](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6281/11683), but I still can't quite figure out what it is that you're protesting. Can you be any more specific?

Comment: In this thread i just explain that moderators should better do nothing until it's really really obvious.