# Deformed priorities of the forum

Tags: discussion

The question that get most rating are the least interesting in terms of engineering/science /technology. Let's stop using rating at all.

Comment: Post some example(s), please.  There are multiple mechanisms at play.

Comment: I don't want to talk about specific names. And i bet you, as a local veteran, know exactly what I mean.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality

Comment: While I have a few hunches, I don't know exactly what you mean.  As I've already mentioned, there's more than one mechanism at play.  In addition to the general Law of Triviality, we also have the Hot Network Questions, which acts like triviality on steroids more often than not.

Comment: What a question's _rating_? Do you mean the vote score?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is obviously just a rant and of no substantial value to the community.

Comment: And you decide what's obvious based on what knowledge?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum No one _decides_. It's a vote.

Comment: Democracy is a vote. It still allows minorities to rule. And i am only asking for a small change.

Comment: But if we stopped voting, where would all the imaginary internet points come from? I'm really unsure what you are trying to convey here.

Comment: Vote, no problem. Don't award for points. A guy who asks a trivial question gets a higher vote. A guy who answers a trivial question gets higher votes. Meaning the vote is meaningless

Comment: You're going to need more than two sentences to convince people of your position. How about a careful explanation of what issue you're trying to solve, and a reasoned argument about why your proposed solution would actually solve it?

Comment: No, i don't think so. I am sure you guys know exactly what i mean, and you definitely have a chance to look up highest voted questions/answers. Nothing to add to this.

Answer (score 3):

This is more about the inner working of Stack Exchange, and has been asked multiple times on Meta. Unfortunately it is not a perfect system, and its flaws are quite well known. But so far, no better alternative has been found to preserve the quality of sites, and given the overall success of the network I think there isn't much interest to change that.

Comment: I think success is relative at best. Many good people are frustrated, many questions are not answered. So site could be much better

Comment: @GregoryKornblum of course, but by success I mean that the network (as a whole) grows in content and in users. I agree that it could be improved, but this is not something we can do within the EE site.

Comment: Ok, let's start with your agreement.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum I'm afraid it won't get you that far